# Metro style : Scrolling with mouse wheel

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, semantic-zoom

I have gridview in the gridview and want to implement the mouse wheel scrolling functionality. So I added this block into  the internal  gridview

```
<GridView.Template>
  <ControlTemplate >
    <ItemsPresenter />
  </ControlTemplate>
</GridView.Template>
```

But in this case swiping doesn't work

How manage I to solve this problem?

part 2.
I'll try to describe this situation more deeply. I have main screen that should realize functionality like on the main screen in Windows 8. It should be zoomed in/out. That's why i use SenaticZoom. In to ZoomIn I put GridView, that contains controls. The control contain own GridView(I need to realize the swiping functionality). I don't know how change this xaml files. Any suggestions? The code of control:

```
<GridView


 x:Name="iGridView"

            Margin="120,0,0,0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ViewSource}}"
                        ItemTemplateSelector ="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}"
                        IsItemClickEnabled="True"


                        MinCellHeight = "450"
                        MinCellWidth = "245"
                        IsSwipedEnabled="True"
                        >

                <GridView.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </GridView.Template>

                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,0,0,20">
                                    <Button

                                        Content="{Binding Title}"
                                        Style="{StaticResource Header}"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="550" Orientation="Vertical"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </GridView.GroupStyle>
            </GridView>
```

and code of the base page

```
<SemanticZoom x:Name="sZoom" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
                    <GridView x:Name="zoomIn" SelectionMode="None"
                                  IsItemClickEnabled="False"
                                  IsSwipeEnabled="False"

                              >
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}"/>
                            </Style>
                        </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <local:Control1 x:Name="Control1" />
                       <local:Control1 x:Name="Control2" />
                    </GridView>
                </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
```

Comment: But mouse wheel should work with just a default GridView? If you create a Grid app - this should just work...

Comment: sorry, but this answer isn't  helpful. i use external gridview in the semantic zoom control, and internal  - for the swiping elements

Comment: From what I remember - it just works, but what you are doing is completely wrong. You are changing the control template of the GridView into something that is missing all the template parts expected by the GridView - including the ScrollViewer.

Comment: @FilipSkakun You absolutely do need to remove the ScrollViewer from the GridView control template, if the GridView is nested in another ScrollViewer. Otherwise, the inner ScrollViewer doesn't need to scroll but still eats the mouse wheel events. The outer ScrollViewer does scroll, but doesn't get the mouse wheel events and as a result, scrolling with the mouse wheel doesn't work.

Comment: But why would you put a GridView in a ScrollViewer if it already has one? I'll need to look at some code again to see how it is done, but I am almost sure the template above is wrong.

Comment: Well, you wouldn't put one GridView directly in a ScrollViewer. But you might put it in a VirutalizingStackPanel together with other controls, and put that in a ScrollViewer.

Comment: Kris Vandermotten, thank you for your advice. I changed template for the internal gridview. Now it doesn't contain ScrollViewer. It seems that it works

Answer (score 2):

It is work GridView style. i remove scrollviewr property

```
<Style x:Key="GridViewInGridViewStyle" TargetType="GridView">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Once"/>
    <Setter Property="IsSwipeEnabled" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerTransitions">
        <Setter.Value>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
                <ContentThemeTransition/>
                <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ItemsPresenter HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Header="{TemplateBinding Header}" HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you re-template the GridView and remove the inner ScrollViewer, then mouse-wheel scrolling will work, but swipe-to-select will not work. If you want both, the trick is to use the AddHandler() method to add a handler for the PointerWheelChanged event and set the e.Handled property to false. That will allow the mouse wheel events to bubble up to your outer ScrollViewer properly:

```
public class CustomGridView : GridView
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var sv = this.GetTemplateChild("ScrollViewer") as UIElement;
        if (sv != null)
            sv.AddHandler(UIElement.PointerWheelChangedEvent, new PointerEventHandler(OnPointerWheelChanged), true);
    }

    private void OnPointerWheelChanged(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = false;
    }
}
```

I implemented this exact scenario and it works for me. Full details here: http://briandunnington.github.com/gridview-in-a-scrollviewer.html

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** sorry, I misread the question. If you place a GridView in a GridView, you do have nested ScrollViewers and you do need that code on the inner GridViews or mousewheel scrolling will not work.

However, why do you nest GridViews in a GridView?

Take a look at the grouping functionality built into winrt.

Alternatively, place the inner GridViews in a simple ItemsControl with a StackPanel with horizontal orientation as the ItemsPanel, and that ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer. If you do place multiple GridViews in a ScrollViewer (directly or indirectly), you do need that code to remove the ScrollViewer from in inner (i.e. nested) GridViews, or mousewheel scrolling will not work.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

That code is needed only if you place the GridView in a ScrollViewer.

If the the GridView is the only thing to display, you don't need to place it in a ScrollViewer, and you don't need that code.

I'm thinking your real question is about how to layout GridView correctly, as the templates included in Visual Studio 11 beta (from consumer preview) do a really bad job there.

Try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid>
      <!-- Back button and page title go here -->
    </Grid>

    <GridView x:Name="itemsGridView" Grid.Row="1"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyListOfSItems}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource myItemTemplate}">
        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapGrid x:Name="itemGridViewPanel" Margin="116,53,116,46"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    </GridView>

</Grid>
```

Now there is only one ScrollViewer, i.e. the one in the GridView, so there are no conflicts from two ScrollViewers nested in each other and the one ScrollViewer handles the mouse automatically.

In addition, the margin is correct, but when scrolling items are allowed to move into the margin area.

Answer (score 0):

This scrolls fine for me:

```
<SemanticZoom>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style
                    TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Width"
                        Value="250" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Height"
                        Value="250" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="FontSize"
                        Value="32" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Apple"/>
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Banana" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Cherry" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Donut" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Eggplant" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Fig" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Grape" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Ham" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Ice Cream" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Jam" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Kale" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Lemon" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Muffin" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Nut" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Orange" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Pear" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Raspberry" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Steak" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Turkey" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Udon" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Vodka" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Wine" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Xanthan Gum" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Yam" />
            <GridViewItem
                Content="Zucchini" />
        </GridView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedInView>
    <SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
        <GridView
            ItemsSource="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ">
            <GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style
                    TargetType="GridViewItem">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Width"
                        Value="400" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="Height"
                        Value="100" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="FontSize"
                        Value="72" />
                </Style>
            </GridView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </GridView>
    </SemanticZoom.ZoomedOutView>
</SemanticZoom>
```

Comment: You misread my question again. I can't see internal gridview in your code. and where is swiping?

Comment: It does not make sense to nest GridViews. What do you mean by swiping? A GridView has a ScrollViewer in the template, so you can always scroll if the content does not fit on screen.

Comment: Sorry, I might have misread part of your question indeed - if you mean the cross-swipe to select functionality - then it should work in a GridView if SelectionMode is not set to None and IsSwipeEnabled="True", but it likely won't work if you nest GridViews, so my answer still holds true - if you can explain what you are trying to achieve with your layout or why you want to nest GridViews - you might get a better answer.

Comment: I have current structure: the main page, that contains gridview in the semaniczoom and controls, that are in the gridview. this controls uses gridview because of 2 reasons -> grouped data and swiping. And I can't change this structure. If I remove ScrollViewer in the GridView, than swiping doesn't work.....

Comment: This is not a supported way to support grouping

Comment: You should check this sample: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e - basically you should look at this XAML file: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e/sourcecode?fileId=44751&pathId=2135334467 - it uses CollectionViewSource bound to a GridView and one GridView for each zoom level of the SemanticZoom control. Nesting GridViews can't work well. You could say there is a bug if one does not work well when hosted inside of another one, but it probably just is not a supported scenario.

Comment: i saw these examples. i USE CollectionViewSource. as I understand you propose  me to remove controls and remove xaml and code  to the main page. sorry but it isn't good solution

Comment: No, I simply say that you should not nest GridViews, but use the built-in mechanism for grouping instead.

Comment: Only 2 elemenets have property IsSwipeEnabled - GridView and ListView. that's all. i need nest gridview

Comment: So you want to be able to swipe the entire group as well as an element in a group?